# JS each каждый второй элемент списка удалить

Tags: javascript

Мне кажется, я не понимаю как работает each. Можете помочь? 
Может не совсем верный заголовок, но проще говоря. У меня есть списки:

```
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">1111</li>
    <li class="li">Alex</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">2222</li>
    <li class="li">Boris</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">3333</li>
    <li class="li">Candy</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">4444</li>
    <li class="li">Donny</li>
</ul>
```

Ну и я пытаюсь удалить каждый второй элемент списка, т.е элементы содержащие Alex, Boris, Candy, Donny.

```
  $('.ul').each(function(){
        $('.ul>li:odd').remove();
    });
```

Проблема в том, что функция бесконечно проходит, и почему то когда удаляет

```
<li class="li">Alex</li>
```

То думает что следующий четный элемент списка, это:

```
<li class="li">2222</li>
```

Но на самом деле, это нечетный элемент совсем другого (следующего) селектора.

P.S. Все решилось, через приписку класса каждому четному, а потом удаление по классу. Но неправильное понимание не дает мне покоя.

```
 $('.ul').each(function(){
        $('.ul>li:odd').addClass('123');
    })
 $('.123').remove();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы вызываете в цикле один и тот же код для всех итераций.

```
$('.ul').each(function() {
  //$('.ul>li:odd').remove();
  $(this).find('li:odd').remove();
});
```

---

В Вашем решении цикл вообще не нужен:

```
$('.ul>li:odd').addClass('123');
$('.123').remove();
```

---

Или без цикла и в одну строчку:

```
$('.ul>li:nth-child(even)').remove();
```

Comment: $(this + ' li:odd').remove(); Я пробовал и так, если вы об этом. И filter тоже...
Только find спас.

Comment: Each()
При вызове функции перебираются все DOM-элементы включенные в выборку объекта jQuery. Каждый раз при вызове переданной функции, в нее передается индекс текущей итерации (начинается с 0). Что еще более важно, переданная функция вызывается в **контексте текущего DOM-элемента, т.е. this будет ссылаться на элемент**

Comment: @Amigo9876 Это мне?

Comment: @Amigo9876 "this будет ссылаться на элемент" - но в Вашем-то коде `this` не используется

Comment: Странно, я пишу @ Igor без пробела, но это исчезает.
Спасибо большое за код. Но я так и не врубаюсь, почему вариант $(this + ' li:odd').remove() не работает. А $(this).find('li:odd').remove(); - работает.
А

Comment: @Amigo9876 Под моим ответом ко мне можно не обращаться - я в любом случае получу извещение о новом комментарии. Это не могло работать, так как Вы складывете DOM-элемент со строкой - с бессмысленным результатом.

Answer (score 2):

Цикл не нужен, потому что  при выборке по селекторам уже итак внутри происходит перебор элементов коллекции и применение метода к ним. Естественно, что в итоге происходит цикл в цикле и на каждой итерации удаляется нечетный элемент для внешнего цикла. В общем, не надо так делать. Просто:

```js
$('.ul>li:odd').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">1111</li>
    <li class="li">Alex</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">2222</li>
    <li class="li">Boris</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">3333</li>
    <li class="li">Candy</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">4444</li>
    <li class="li">Donny</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Есть небольшая опасность в том, что нумерация элементов `li` здесь становится сквозной.

Comment: `$('.ul>li:nth-child(even)').remove();`